# Squarespace iframe causes banner image not to show

Tags: html, css, iframe, squarespace

So I have a banner image as part of a template for squarespace and I'm also using an iframe in my post but when I do, it causes the image not to appear. I see that there's a data-src attribute on the img element but the src attribute is not being set

`<img data-src="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/52f67893e4b087ee0883a2e0/t/5500dd5ce4b0a4b6b53c65d3/1426120064231/IMG_2466.jpg" data-image="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/52f67893e4b087ee0883a2e0/t/5500dd5ce4b0a4b6b53c65d3/1426120064231/IMG_2466.jpg" data-image-dimensions="2500x1339" data-image-focal-point="0.5,0.5" alt="IMG_2466.jpg">`

Does anyone know why this would be happening and why the iframe would cause this? It works fine on other pages that don't have the iframe.

The affected page is here:

http://www.typeatrips.com/barcelona-spain/

Answer (score 0):

Try switching the width to ' width="99% ' , I had it at 100% and was experiencing the same problem (no images/content appeared on the page, but reappeared when I deleted the iframe), and making it 1% narrower fixed it! not sure why but it did!

Comment: sorry, width="99%"

Comment: Modify your Answer instead of commenting about the typo.